# Which program wrote a file?

Tags: windows-7

Is there any way to tell which program wrote out a specific file or if not is there any monitoring program i can run to find out?

Specifics:
I run a program called sandboxie which cleans up all the cookies when i run chrome. I only run chrome (never IE or Firefox). Somehow tracking cookies are still getting on my machine (doubleclick) and i want to see what program is writing them out.

Found this program: http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/track-real-time-file-changes-in-directories-with-track-folder-changes/

But its not going to help because it doesn't tell you which program wrote the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use [Windows Auditing](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/advanced-security-auditing-in-windows-7-and-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx) to [monitor file and folder access](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310399).

Answer (score 2):

Try Process Monitor, a sysinternals tool.

Comment: I don't think that is going to work. I have used process monitor many times but either i would have to keep it running for days (never tried that before) or i would have to look at it right when the file is written out.

Comment: How big would the logs be if it needed to run for days or weeks?