# Software to track what files and folders an application accesses or creates?

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which program wrote a file?](https://superuser.com/questions/394113/which-program-wrote-a-file)

Is there a software for windows that can use the winapi or something to detect folder access or file accesses by that application?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Process Monitor](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/advanced-security-auditing-in-windows-7-and-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx) to view/log file/folder activity and set up filters to narrow down the focus to just the files/folders/processes you are interested in.

You can also use Windows Auditing <sup>[[1]](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)[[2]](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)[[3]](http://www.petri.co.il/windows_auditing.htm)</sup> to monitor file/folder access.