# Looking for software that displays realtime access to files on HDD

Tags: hard-drive, real-time, file-monitoring, disk-monitoring

I'm looking a some software that will show me any and all files that are being accessed, modified, created, etc... in real time on my HDD. I don't know what to even look for. Process Explorer didn't help.

Running on Windows 7

Comment: Process Mointor shows that info

Comment: Going to need an operating system here (htop, top also show that info)

Comment: @soandos, I think it’s safe to assume Windows since they said that *Process Explorer didn’t help*.

Comment: You can also try [Windows Auditing](http://superuser.com/questions/394113/which-program-wrote-a-file).

Answer (score 1):

The Sysinternals tool [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) from Technet works for me.